# Matlab complex matrix matching (matching highest and lowest)

Tags: performance, algorithm, matlab, sorting, correlation

I am trying to match lowest points in one matrix to highest ones in another matrix. (more specifically using comparing points in one matrix which refer to another to find the lowest one). Imagine I have a matrices `myData1` and `myData2` which are 1x450 and another one which `grid` is 450x450. now `myData` is a concatenation of 450 matrices which has added up to N. I would like to compare points with highest values in `myData1` and `myData2` to be compared to the `grid` and choose lowest ones. I cannot find the best and most efficient way to do this without loop. (I can already achieve result using nested loops). Is there a neat way to do this comparison and get best result?

**EDIT** adding a solution

```
[~,sorted1] = sort(-myData1);
[~,sorted2] = sort(-myData2);
lowestPoint = Inf;
for i=1:length(sorted1) % sorted2 will have the same length
   val = grid(sorted1(i),sorted2(i)) % will give the value in the grid
   % we are looking for lowest one of them.
   if(val<lowestPoint)
        lowestPoint = val
        result = [result;sorted1(i),sorted2(i)]
    end
end
```

Actually imagine it's a nested loop to compare `sorted1(i)` with `sorted2(j)`. This is something I'm looking for. I want it to be done in the most efficient way. My calculations already take about 1 sec. I want this to be done much faster. Also I need the record of `~` for both `myData` but for the sake of simplicity here let's say I have taken care of that.

Comment: Please add your current solution to the question.

Comment: `val` could be vectorized using `val=grid(sub2ind(size(grid),sorted1,sorted2));`. Maybe someone else finds a solution for `result`